# displaying prop in filtered function - axios, vue3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3

how can i display a prop in filteredProducts when fetching data using axios. i have passed through a prop like below.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filteredProducts: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
 axios
 .get('/src/stores/sneakers.json')
 .then(response => { const products = response.data
  this.filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.name.includes('Nike'))
})
  },
  computed: {
        resultCount () {
            return Object.keys(this.filteredProducts).length 
        },
    },
  props: {
    brand: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
```

I would like to replace 'Nike' with brand.name as that is being passed through. Much appreciated

Comment: `this.brand?.name` is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   

     export default {
              data() {
                return {
                  products: [],
                };
              },
              mounted() {
                   this.getSneakers();
              },
              methods: {
                 getSneakers() {
                 axios
                  .get('/src/stores/sneakers.json')
                   .then(response => { 
                  this.products = response.data ?? [];
                      })
                  }
               },
              computed: {
                    resultCount () {
                        return this.filteredProducts?.length ?? 0
                    },
                    brandName() {
                        return this.brand?.name ?? "";
                    },
                    filteredProducts () {
                        return this.products?.filter(
        product => product.name?.toLowerCase()?.includes(this.brandName.toLowerCase())
                   )
                    },
                },
              props: {
                brand: {
                  type: Object,
                },
              },
          }
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks good. I am quite new to vuejs, how can i change the API call to a method?

Comment: @chrisjarn pls check my updated solution

Answer (score 0):

Choose the products that are named 'Nike' and pass them into `filteredProducts`. After that you can change the names using a computed property and use that in the template.

```
<template>
  <div 
    v-for="(item, i) in nikeProducts"
    :key="i"
  >
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    brand: {
      type: Object
    }
  }
  data() {
    return {
      filteredProducts: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    axios
      .get('/src/stores/sneakers.json')
      .then(response => { 
          const products = response.data
          this.filteredProducts = products.filter(product => product.name.include('Nike'));
      })
  },
  computed: {
    nikeProducts() {
      return this.filteredProducts.map(product => product.name = this.brand.name)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```